# About Twisted Documents

Tags: python, twisted

I am a beginner for Twisted. Recently, I am reading the book "Twisted Network Programming Essentials".The Example 2-3 In this book as below:

```
class QuickDisconnectProtocol(protocol.Protocol): 

def connectionMade(self): 

    print "Connected to %s." % self.transport.getPeer( ).host 

    self.transport.loseConnection( )
```

==================================

`self.transport.loseConnection( )`

where is the member "transport"?
I couldn't find that one in Protocol.

Same question when it comes to Ex2-4...

Does anyone have a clue on how to read Twisted Documents? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def makeConnection(self, transport): ([source][1])
    """
    overridden in twisted.protocols.amp.BinaryBoxProtocol,
    twisted.protocols.ftp.ProtocolWrapper, twisted.protocols.ftp.SenderProtocol, 
    twisted.protocols.policies.ProtocolWrapper, 
    twisted.protocols.stateful.StatefulProtocol`

    Make a connection to a transport and a server.
    This sets the 'transport' attribute of this Protocol, and calls the connectionMade() 
    callback.
    """
```

The transport is the connection to the whatever you're using, like telnet, SSH, a file, etc. Search the online API docs for `transport` and see i.e.

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.conch.ssh.transport.SSHTransportBase.html

Here are some if the transports that exist, from 
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.ITransport.html

```
Known subclasses: twisted.conch.insults.insults.ITerminalTransport, 
twisted.conch.telnet.ITelnetTransport, twisted.internet.interfaces.IProcessTransport, 
twisted.internet.interfaces.ITCPTransport

Known implementations: twisted.conch.ssh.channel.SSHChannel, 
twisted.internet._posixstdio.StandardIO, twisted.internet._win32stdio.StandardIO, 
twisted.internet.abstract.FileDescriptor, twisted.internet.iocpreactor.abstract.FileHandle, 
twisted.internet.protocol.FileWrapper, twisted.protocols.loopback._LoopbackTransport, 
twisted.protocols.loopback.LoopbackRelay
```

Depending on where you want to connect to, you use one of them when you call `makeConnection(transport)`, and when you do that, it **becomes** an attribute of the protocol.

Comment: Thank you!  I caught that "This sets the 'transport' attribute of this Protocol", Where can I find the "'transport' attribute of this Protocol" in the doc? I checked the implementaion of some protocol such as ssh, but have no clue on where the attribute transport is?

Comment: The transport isn't part of the protocol -- any protocol can use may different kinds of transport. It's passed to the protocol when `makeConnection` is called (I assume by the user), and Python assigns it to the `transport` atrribute then. So, first you pick a transport, (I've edited my post to list some), then you call`self.makeConnection(transport)` and it __becomes__ an attribute of the protocol.